# Error on LSTM input and target shapes

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm working on a time series forecasting problem using Keras' LSTM. I've done the shaping and batching of the dataset on a TimeseriesGenerator, but I'm not sure I'm getting the results I want so I'm trying to keep it simple for debugging.

My data consists of 1 sample with 100 timesteps and 1 feature, and I'm taking the last 30 values for testing. I can't figure out what's wrong with the shape of the training x/y datasets.

```
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=30, shuffle=False)
train_x = np.reshape(train_x, (1, train_x.shape[0], train_x.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 16, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1],train_x.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_split=0.1, batch_size = 16, epochs = 300, shuffle=False,verbose=1)
```

> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 69 target samples.

Answer (score 0):

Your reshaping of the features creates an array of shape (1, xshape[0], xshape[1]).
This means you only have 1 sample, your y has 69 samples. The size of both has to match. If you have 1 input X, you have to pass 1 Y.

Comment: Yes, I understand how I'm shaping my data but I don't want 69 samples with 1 timestep each, since it defeats the purpose of using an LSTM. I want only 1 sample of 69 timesteps. How should I reshape x and y ?

Comment: I don´t know how your data looks like. Seems like you have 69 y values?

Answer (score 0):

so your data looks like below code 8 time steps and 1 sample

```
arr=array([[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]]])
```

but instead you have 100 time steps instead of 8 time steps like above example
so if I want to reshape above array to make it 4 samples and each sample is 2 time steps the code will be:

```
reshaped_arr=arr.reshape(4,2,1)
```

use above example as guide